# Fluent API - how to map custom relation table?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, fluent

I have class which may look like this:

```
public class Group
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Group> IsMemberOf {get; set;}
}
```

Group can be member of other groups. Id db I have table Group and table GroupGroup. In ModelBuilder I use this code to define mapping.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<GroupGroup>()
            .ToTable("GroupGroup")
            .HasKey(e => new { e.GroupId, e.MemberGroupId });
modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
            .ToTable("Group")
            .Ignore(e => e.IsMemberOf);
```

Well, my question is how to map groups from relation table GroupGroup to property IsMemberOf with Fluent API? I am very new to ef, Fluent API and such and I know I should let ef to create its own relation table, but I must use this way because of connection to AD and other systems. Is there any way how achieve this?

Thanks a lot for any hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need a many-to-many association, because of this `GroupGroup` association table. One way to map this is:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
    .HasMany(g => g.IsMemberOf)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("ChildGroupId")
               .MapRightKey("GroupId")
               .ToTable("GroupGroup")
        );
```

That means that you don't have a `GroupGroup` entity class in your class model. EF populates the `IsMemberOf` collection by setting up all necessary joins if you execute a LINQ statement like:

```
var groups = context.Groups.Include(g => g.IsMemberOf).ToList();
```

I don't know why you have this line `.Ignore(e => e.IsMemberOf)` in your mapping, but that should be deleted.

You can even make the mapping go both ways:

```
public class Group
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Group> IsMemberOf { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Group> HasMembers { get; set; }
}
```

And the mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
    .HasMany(g => g.IsMemberOf)
    .WithMany(g => g.HasMembers)
    .Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("ChildGroupId")
               .MapRightKey("GroupId")
               .ToTable("GroupGroup")
        );
```